# How did we get the result in the 2nd iff statement?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

[image]

I don't understand the reasoning behind 10 is congruent to one under mod 9 implies that we can get the third statement below :

[image]

Can I get an explanation on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, $10 \equiv 1 \mod 9$

Therefore, $$10^i \equiv1 \mod9$$
Hence, $$a_i 10^i \equiv a_i \mod9$$ for all $i=0,1,2,\cdots n$. 
Adding these up$$a_0+a_1 10+a_2 10^2 + \cdots a_n 10^n \equiv a_0+a_1 1+a_2 1^2 + \cdots a_n 1^n \mod 9 $$

Comment: what are the "these" that we should add up?

Comment: Clearly you mean $a_i10^i \equiv a_i \bmod(9)$. Otherwise, this is correct.

Comment: @user459897 if $a \equiv b \bmod(m)$ and $c \equiv d \bmod(m)$ then $a + c \equiv b + d \bmod(m)$.

Comment: So if a is congruent to b mod m and c is congruent to d mod m and e is congruent to f mod m,..... y is congruent to z mod m. we can say a+c+...+y is congruent to b +d +...z mod m?

Comment: @user459897 Yes.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

reduced the $10^n$ to $1^n$ because they have the same remainder on division by 9

Answer (score 0):

since $$10\equiv 1\mod 9$$ we get $$10^n\equiv 1^n\equiv 1\mod 9$$